# Best practice for GitHub project with personal keys

Tags: r, github

I am putting up a project I did that makes use of the Goodreads API - this means using a personal API key.

I would like for that not to be available (on the raw script of the RMD document), and yet I would like all code to be self-contained.

What are the best practices for doing this?

Currently, I cannot think of a way to have self-contained code AND have the API key be unavailable for viewing in the raw version.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/205606/257

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going off of Bill the Lizard's comment, you basically want to do this:

Create a new R file and put your key in it, call it `config.R`

```
##### config.R
Sys.setenv(GOODREADS_KEY = "YOUR_KEY_HERE")
##### end config.R
```

Then in your primary code, run your configuration file:

`source("/path/config.R")`

In your Git repository you can upload a dummy copy of `config.R`, but make sure not to include the actual key, so you would literally keep "YOUR KEY HERE" in the public version.

You should not let others make API calls using your private key.